# How to implement distributed transaction in CouchDB?

Tags: hadoop, couchdb, distributed-transactions

We are moving our database from oracle to couchDB, for one of the use case is to implement the distributed transaction management. 
For Ex: Read the data from JMS Queue and update it in multiple document, if any thing fails then revert back and throws an exception to JMS queue.
As we know couchDB does not support distributed transaction management.
Can you please suggest any alternative strategy to implement this or any other way out?

Comment: Please see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735979/couchdb-couchbase-mongodb-transaction-emulation

Answer (score 1):

More than technical aspects I feel you might be interested in the bottom line of that.

As mentionned distributed transactions are not possible - this notion doesn't even exist, because it is not necessary. Indeed, unlike in the relational world,  95% of the time when you feel that you need them it means that you are doing something wrong.

I'll be straightforward with you : dumping your relational data into couchdb will end up being a nightmare both for writes and reads. For the first you'll say : how can I do transactions ? For the laters : how can I do joins ? Both are impossible and are concepts which do not even exist.

The convenient conclusions - too - many people reach is that "CouchDb is not enterprise ready or ACID enough". But the truth is you need to take the time to rethink your data structures.

You need to rethink your data structures and make them document oriented because if you don't you are off the intended usage of couchdb - and as you know this is risky territory.

Read on DDD and aggregates design, and turn your records into DDD entities and aggregates. So there'd be an ETL layer to CouchDb. If you don't have the time to do that I'd recommend not using CouchDb - as much as I love it.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB doesn't have properties which are necessary for distributed transactions so it's impossible. All major distributed transaction algorithms (Two-Phase commit protocol, RAMP and Percolator-style distributed transactions, you can find details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297766/best-practices-of-distributed-transactionsjava/37360091#37360091)) require linearizability on the record level. Unfortunately CouchDB is an AP solution (in the CAP theorem sense) so it can't even guarantee record-level consistency.

Of cause you can disable replication to make CouchDB consistent but then you'll lose fault-tolerance. Another option is to use CouchDB as a storage and to build a consistent database on top of it but it's an overkill for your task and doesn't use any CouchDB-specific feature. The third option is to use CRDT but it works only if your transactions are commutative.